# How can I use fineuploader with Amazon S3 in my directory structure?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I am using fineuploader http://fineuploader.com/ and Amazon S3. Every thing works fine when I am running everything from one folder but can not get it to work in my directory structure.

I have the following directory structure in application (framework: https://github.com/panique/mini)

```
application
--controller
----album.php
--libs
----s3demo.php
--model

public
--css
--img
--js
----application.js
```

I have changed the endpoint in fineuploader javascript (application.js) to

```
    signature: {
        endpoint: url + "/album/s3upload"
    },
```

My function s3upload in my controller album.php

```
   public function s3upload() {
   require APP . '/libs/s3demo.php';
}
```

When I run the code I get the following error message in the browser NET tab -> Response

> **Notice**:  Undefined index: _method in
>   **/home/connecti/public_html/application/libs/s3demo.php** on line
>   **78**
>  
>  **Warning**:  Cannot modify header
>   information - headers already sent by (output started at
>   /home/connecti/public_html/application/libs/s3demo.php:77) in
>   **/home/connecti/public_html/application/libs/s3demo.php** on line
>   **103**
>  
>  **Notice**:  Undefined index: headers in
>   **/home/connecti/public_html/application/libs/s3demo.php** on line
>   **109**
>  {"invalid":true}

What is wrong? Do I neeed to change something in fineuploader javascript?

s3demo.php : https://github.com/FineUploader/server-examples/blob/master/php/s3/s3demo.php

The javascript code I am using: http://fineuploader.com/demos.html (Upload Files Directly to Amazon S3)

Comment: It looks like your server is including log messages in the response.  You'll want to turn that off.

Comment: My file uploading is not working. Strange thing is that my code works fine if I run it outside mvc structure (everything from a folder I public). I will test turn off all debug mode and logging.